# Where to host Smartsheets API code

Tags: smartsheet-api

I am interested in learning to use the Smartsheets API. In the past I created workflows in Google Apps Script, which has a built in IDE that houses the script. Does Smartsheets have something similar? If not, where is a common place to keep your code and have it react to webhooks/events?

Regards,

Shawn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API is just a way to communicate between your application and Smartsheet - there is no hosting for your executable code. Smartsheet [provides a number of SDKs](https://www.smartsheet.com/developers/sdks) to help make the calls easier to perform, but in theory you could use any language to make the REST commands. So, pretty much any service that allows executable code would work, such as Amazon AWS, Google Cloud, Microsoft Azure, or others. [Here's a brief comparison of services.](https://www.sitepoint.com/a-side-by-side-comparison-of-aws-google-cloud-and-azure/)

Answer (score 0):

You can start developing on your own computer before you worry about cloud deployment. See the getting started guide and samples here: https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/getting-started

If you really need to respond to webhooks, your code will have to run somewhere that accepts incoming HTTP calls from the Internet without being blocked by a firewall. This could be in your data center, any of cloud services, or via a tunnel such as https://ngrok.com/